# Extract names from a list using map() function

Tags: r, purrr

I already have a list contains all functions in dplyr by using this code

```
content <- mget(ls("package:dplyr"), inherits = TRUE)
dplyr_functions <- Filter(is.function, content)
```

The result I wanna get is just like the result of

```
names(dplyr_functions)
```

It will be a chr vector containing all function names in dplyr package.
But when I use `map()` function, my code is like:

```
dplyr_name <- map_chr(dplyr_functions, names)
```

There is an error said,

> "Result 1 must be a single string, not NULL of length 0"

So I just want to know what the error mean? How can I use `map_chr` to get a vector containing all names in *dplyr_functions*?

Comment: You can't get the names from a list when using `map()`. Those aren't "in" the list. Maybe use `imap()` instead which iterates both the names and the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` loop through the list element's content "value" e.g. `dplyr_functions[[1]]` and so on, not through the element as in `dplyr_functions[1]`, try both to see the difference. Hence `names(dplyr_functions[[1]])` returns `NULL` and `map_chr` fails, while `names(dplyr_functions[1])` returns `%>%` and `map_chr` could work.

So we can loop through the list index and subset using the 2nd method or use `imap` which designed to loop through the list names.

```
library(purrr)
map_chr(seq_along(dplyr_functions), ~names(dplyr_functions[.x])) 
#or
imap_chr(dplyr_functions, ~.y) %>% unname()
```